# Water activities on West Scotland's Lochs

Tags: scotland, water-sports, lakes

Since Scotland is full of small lakes that promise nice views due to their proximity to mountains, I am wondering if I can rent a boat/kayak/canoe on some of them? I'd be particularly interested in a place that is accessible by car (or by 0.5-1h hike from a parking), where I can go on water for a few hours and ideally reach the other side of the lake, where I could have a picnic/see some old ruins/relax on a remote beach or simply enjoy a beautiful view — basically something that would make crossing the lake worthwhile. Oh, I'm not really interested in motorboats, I'd rather paddle by myself.

I am especially interested in lochs in the West: around Loch Lomond, Oban, Mull, Fort William and Skye. Is this at all possible? Could you recommend a good loch for this?

Answer (score 3):

Over that side I'd be far more tempted to go sea kayaking - check out http://www.seakayakoban.com/ , or my favourite, http://www.rockhopperscotland.co.uk/ for some amazing routes - but if you want to kayak on lochs in the west of Scotland, the following should be useful:

Loch Lomond has quite a few water sports centres that will hire kayaks or canoes.

- [Can you experience](http://www.canyouexperience.com/) are pretty good if you already know how to paddle, or if you need training
- the [Lomond Kayak Club](https://www.facebook.com/LomondKayakClub) cater more to locals, but they do hire kayaks, and do training sessions occasionally throughout the year
- The [Loch Lomond Outdoor Centre](http://www.lochlomondoutdoorcentre.com/activity_list.shtml) is probably better suited if you are experienced. They have some good loch - river routes
- [Lomond Shores](http://www.lochlomondshores.com/visitor-information/) do canoe hire as well - not sure if they do training, or if they just expect you to know what you are doing. This bit is really a tourist centre, so not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

At loch lomond shores you can rent a canoe or kayak. I did that a couple of years ago but the area where you can go with the kayak is small and restricted.

I found it frustrating. The folks renting the kayak are health & safety mad. Not seasoned kayak people.

I'd recommend contacting the local kayak club (You could try Glasgow Kayak Club) and enquiry from there.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a bit before accepting the answer though, maybe someone knows a particular place where I could go to.